# Motion and the Universe

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, universe, relative-motion

In physics class today, I learned that motion is relative, and to determine if an object is moving or not, you need to have a stationary reference point.

Well, that got me thinking:

How can you determine if the reference point is stationary? According to what I learned, you'd have to have another point. So, how can you know if the *last* point is stationary? Would you compare it to the object that you are trying to determine if it's moving or not in the first place?

However, after some thinking, I noticed that there is an infinite number of points in the universe which means that there will never be a "last" point. So is the universe an open circle that appears to be closed no matter how much you zoom in on it? Nothing is absolute and everything is just recursions, recursions, recursions.

Obviously, we as humans cannot figure out the universe unless it wants us to, but still, talking about this is better than playing games right? :)

What are some of your thoughts on the universe? Or is there something wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, there is no absolute frame of reference. If two spacecraft passed each other, they could each consider their self as standing still and the other moving past them. If you were in a spacecraft, and you looked out and saw the entire Universe moving past, you could still consider your self as standing still, and the Universe as moving. All of the physical laws would be the same for each frame of reference. This is one of the basics of Einstein's theories of relativity. Welcome to relativity, it is fascinating to study.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the fact, that you have been give wrong information, which, as you pointed out, don't even make sense.

If the motion is relative, then of course you cannot determine if an object is moving or not. It is simply not a property of object itself, but rather property of your description/viewpoint of the object. Then, the reference point could be taken stationary as a definition and in the sentence you mentioned, the word stationary could be used to highlight the fact that the reference point is indeed stationary in your description -> which is trivial claim, since every point is stationary with respect to itself. There is no additional information, you are just highlighting some (trivial) property of any reference point.

That being said, not all motion is relative. Without being completely general - this holds only for a class of motions without acceleration. Now, from purely kinematical viewpoint, this is again circular reasoning. If you have some reference point to which some object is accelerating, you can easily imagine another accelerating point with the same acceleration as your object which would lead to the object being stationary with zero acceleration with respect to this new reference point. However, the physics in such a frame would not be the same.

There is special kind of a reference point called inertial, with respect to which all the observed accelerations of the objects can be found to have its cause in interaction between themselves. F.e. if you would be at rest to this reference point and nothing would push you, then you would still remain at rest. Then there is a question wheter such reference point even exists, and the answer is practically yes (it depends on the level of approximation you are ready to accept).  One such reference point could be considered to be some fixed point on the ground of Earth. When you stand stationary on your legs and nothing is pushing you, then you are remaining at rest with respect to the ground without any effort from your part. This is not the case f.e. in moving train that is going into turning move - you do have a problem remaining at rest with respect to this train. But if the train is not accelerating and is moving in a straight line with the same speed, you again have no problem with remaining at rest with respect to it. This is because any point that is in constant motion with respect to some inertial reference point is again inertial.

Now, the fact that you can remain in rest on the Earth is actually given by the fact that you are being supported by the ground, otherwise you would fall due to gravity. But this does not prohibit the reference point to be inertial, because you know the source of this force - it is gravity of the Earth. It comes from interaction between objects, so it is ok (this point was revised by Einstein's general relativity, but it holds good in classical physics).

To recapitulate - to observe motion (any type of motion) you need to have some reference point. For any kind of motion, there can always be found such reference point in which the object in motion is stationary. However, not all such reference points are equal. There is special class of reference points, called inertial, with respect to which all the changes in motion of objects are due to interaction between them. With respect to these reference points, the physics is special. And there are more reference points with property of being inertial - all of them moving with constant velocities with respect to each other. But the physics with respect to all of these points is equal so we have no way of choosing one of these points over the others. And this is called relativity principle - relativity of motion. The relativity is only for this special class of reference points.

Now, to give you a little deeper understanding (hopefully i will not add confusion), in our real Universe, even more special reference point can be picked. This is the reference point in which galaxies are on average stationary (note, this property does not care about position of the reference point, only about its motion). With respect to this reference point, the physics of our real Universe is the most simple - so we can choose it as an absolute reference point without having bad consciense. But this possibility does not come from the physical laws as such, it comes from the way our universe is made.

Physical laws can describe any configuration of galaxies, the laws are completely general in this way. But our Universe has one particular kind of configuration and this configuration will allow to find more special reference point than just inertial one.

It is kind of like on Earth. If you are doing statics of some building, then obviously there is one reference frame in which it is most convenient to work with, and that is the frame in which the building is stationary (i.e. ground). You will not use frame of reference of moving train, even though it is still inertial and all physics laws will remain the same.

This is coincidental for Earth - there is no deep reason why Earth moves the way it does. It simply happened historically, so we cannot use Earth as absolute refence point with good conscience to overthrow relativity principle. But in cosmology, this is not so clear. We don't know wheter, there is some deep fundamental reason why our Universe is the way it is, or it is coincidental like Earth, so it is opened for revision of relativity principle. But even if cosmology would overthrow the relativity principle on fundamental level, the principle would be just as relevant for all the physics it is relevant right now, just as Newtonian gravitation is still relevant description of gravity in its domain of applicability, even though on fundamental level it was overthrown by general relativity (some would perhaps rather say extended instead of overthrown, but conceptually it is completely different theory).

Answer (score 0):

If your reference point is a theoretical dot in the universe, then by the time you finished reading this it'd be a few thousand kilometres closer or farther to you. So on a intergalactic scale everything is moving, always.

Comment: And yet anything can consider itself motionless.

Answer (score 0):

An easy example would be the Highway:

Let's say you drive with 100km/h, then, someone overtakes you with 120km/h. Compared to you, the other car only seems to drive 20 km/h fast